# Create Custom Content Type using Client Object Model

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model, content-type

I need to create custom content type from a given guid for a SharePoint site using Client Object Model. However, in the constructor of

```
ContentTypeId ctid = new ContentTypeId()
```

there is no facility to provide value for GUID.

If one notices server side object model to perform the same operation as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798370.aspx then there is an option to provide GUID in the constructor as

```
SPContentTypeId myContentTypeId = new SPContentTypeId("0x010100FA0963FA69A646AA916D2E41284FC9D9");
```

Why there is such a difference between Client Object Model and Server Object Model?
Is there any possible work around?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to set the content type id in CSOM.  Not sure why the difference.  The closest you can get is setting the `ParentContentType` value, but that leaves the final two digits to be randomly generated.  This is how to create a content type in CSOM:

```
var clientContext = new ClientContext( siteUrl );
// For SharePoint Online
var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, secureStringPassword);
clientContext.Credentials = credentials;

var contentTypes = clientContext.Web.ContentTypes;
var contentTypeCreationInformation = new ContentTypeCreationInformation
                                     {
                                         Name = "Content Type Name",
                                         Description = "Description",
                                         Group = "Group",
                                         ParentContentType = ContentType // Must be content type object
                                     };
var contentType = contentTypes.Add( contentTypeCreationInformation );
clientContext.Load( contentType );
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
clientContext.Dispose();
```

Comment: This code does not give the option to provide the Content type ID either though

Comment: CSOM doesn't provide a method to set the ID on creation.  The closest is setting the ParentContentType parameter, but that still leaves the last two digits to random.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely possible to create content types and specifying a content type id:

```
Web rootWeb = clientContext.Site.RootWeb;
rootWeb.ContentTypes.Add(new ContentTypeCreationInformation {
    Id = "0x0100BDD5E43587AF469CA722FD068065DF5D",
    Name = "My Content Type"
});
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Make sure your using the `SP2013 Client Components SDK` with at least version `15.0.4569.1000` (current is `16.0.3104.1200`) ([Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2014/02/28/ftc-to-cam-create-content-types-with-specific-ids-using-csom.aspx)).

Latest SDK download: [Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585)